# VB5 to VB6 Migration

Tags: vb6-migration, vb5

what is the best way of migrating VB5 to VB6. which version of Visual Studio helps this and what all precautions/considerations we need to take care before migration. Is there any approach notes available anywhere in internet

Comment: Any reason of still using historical Visual Basic versions ?

Comment: I have been migrate from VB6 to VB.NET 2005 .. It's not too difficult

Comment: I am specifically looking for VB5 to VB6. The customer is keen on this

Answer (score 3):

For the most part you can think of VB6 as a superset of VB5, there is nothing really to upgrade, just taking advantage of the new functionality.  Just open the project in VS6, and you should be good to go.

I would instead try to sell the customer on a VB.Net upgrade.  It is not just opening the project and you are done, but it will allow you to have much more powerful tools/environment.

Comment: Furthermore, the customer is probably more likely to find developers over time who will be able to work on a VB.NET app than VB5 or VB6.